# Python: Efficiently check if value in a list is in another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, **user_df**, with ~500,000 rows with the following format:

```
|  id  |  other_ids   |
|------|--------------|
|  1   |['abc', efg'] |
|  2   |['bbb']       |
|  3   |['ccc', 'ddd']|
```

I also have a list, **other_ids_that_clicked**, with ~5000 items full of other ids:

```
 ['abc', 'efg', 'ccc']
```

I'm looking to de-dupe **other_ids_that_clicked** using **user_df** by adding another column in df for when a value in other_ids is in user_df['other_ids'] as such:

```
|  id  |  other_ids   |  clicked  |
|------|--------------|-----------|
|  1   |['abc', efg'] |     1     |
|  2   |['bbb']       |     0     |
|  3   |['ccc', 'ddd']|     1     |
```

The way I'm checking is by looping through **other_ids_that_clicked** for each row in **user_df**.

```
def otheridInList(row):
  isin = False
  for other_id in other_ids_that_clicked:
    if other_id in row['other_ids']:
        isin = True
        break
    else: 
        isin = False
  if isin:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

This is taking forever, so I was looking for suggestions on best ways to approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually speed this up quite a bit. Take out the column, convert it into its own dataframe, and use `df.isin` to do some checking -

```
l = ['abc', 'efg', 'ccc']
df['clicked'] = pd.DataFrame(df.other_ids.tolist()).isin(l).any(1).astype(int)

   id   other_ids  clicked
0   1  [abc, efg]        1
1   2       [bbb]        0
2   3  [ccc, ddd]        1
```

---

**Details**

First, convert `other_ids` into a list of lists -

```
i = df.other_ids.tolist()

i
[['abc', 'efg'], ['bbb'], ['ccc', 'ddd']]
```

Now, load it into a new dataframe -

```
j = pd.DataFrame(i)

j
     0     1
0  abc   efg
1  bbb  None
2  ccc   ddd
```

Perform checks with `isin` -

```
k = j.isin(l)

k
       0      1
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True  False
```

`clicked` can be computed by checking if `True` is present in *any* row, with `df.any`. The result is converted into an integer.

```
k.any(1).astype(int)

0    1
1    0
2    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I had the same answer as yours except the first step but see the difference: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df['other_id'].tolist()): 757 µs ± 38.9 µs ,  %timeit df['other_id'].apply(pd.Series): 1.88 ms ± 54.6 µs. Its crazy

Comment: @Vaishali I learned this the hard way from jezrael... whenever you can use `apply(pd.Series)`, you can also use `pd.DataFrame(...tolist())` to the same effect... almost always! It's almost like a recipe in a pandas cookbook.

Comment: So its faster to construct a dataframe again than applying a function to it:)

Comment: @Vaishali Almost always... timings vary depending on the data. The problem is that `apply` is a glorified loop, while calling the constructor is much faster because the code behind it is more powerful... haha you probably already know this.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The details make it very clear on what's going on. However, I am still getting 0 for all my values in df['clicked'] for some reason.

Comment: @user8766186 You're welcome. Do let me know how it fares performance-wise compared to your old loopy solution.

Comment: @coldspeed - it pretty much ran instantly (the loopy solution is still running in the back from like 30 minutes ago haha). 

However, I tried to do a test by taking values directly from the df['other_id'] but it is giving me 0 on all the values in df['clicked'] for some reason.

Comment: @user8766186 Hmm, could there be leading spaces in your column or in your lists?

Comment: I don't believe so - I tried as a test as well:

import pandas as pd

data = [['1', ['abc, efg']],['2', ['bbb']],['3', ['ccc', 'ddd']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'other_ids'])

l = ['abc', 'efg', 'ccc']
df['clicked'] = pd.DataFrame(df.other_ids.tolist()).isin(l).any(1).astype(int)

print df['clicked']

0    0
1    0
2    1
Name: clicked, dtype: int64

Comment: I'm not sure how to format - in comments. Can I send you a chat message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161475/discussion-between-user8766186-and-cs).

Answer (score 3):

Using `set`

```
df['New']=(df.other_ids.apply(set)!=(df.other_ids.apply(set)-set(l))).astype(int)
df
Out[114]: 
   id   other_ids  New
0   1  [abc, efg]    1
1   2       [bbb]    0
2   3  [ccc, ddd]    1
```

Comment: Nice... using set operations.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  `pd.DataFrame(df.other_ids.tolist())` shock me !  learn it : -)